# What's wrong with Automatic Weights doing to my Normal?

Tags: materials, armature, normals, unity, .fbx

I'm having trouble with my model in Unity..

I made the model with Blender, put on the Armature(using Automatic Weights), and found everything works great.

But as you can see in the image, when I took it to Unity, the model is getting a light reversed.

So I erased my Armature and took it to Unity, and then everything worked fine.

I tried making new Armature on my model, then the problem happens again.

I'm pretty sure something is messed up with my model.

Please help me guys.. I'm desperate :(

[image: Model with Armature On]

[image: Model with Armature Erased]

---

I sure did recalculated..

But recalculating only made situation worse.

The model still took light reversed + Normal Flipped and gone invisible outside. :(
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate your model's normals 2.79 - Edit model select all with CTRL-N
                                 2.8 - Edit mode select all with Shift - N

Edit:
There might be 2 main problem 
 1. Your unity materials shader type is not opaque
 2. Your model has inside faces I mean uncessary wrong faces If there is you has to delete them and recalculate again

Comment: I added more detail. I did recalculated and it made situation worse..